# PHP JSON foreach only returns first character

Tags: php, json, foreach

I've been trying to mess around with some JSON data for an idea that I have, but when I try to `foreach` loop through the JSON, it's only returns the first character for all the data and not just the `first_name` in my test.

**Code**

```
<?php
  $jsondata ='{"first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe","guest_link":"test test","id":"3"}';
  $json = json_decode($jsondata, true);
  ?>
  <?php foreach($json as $item) : ?>
    <p>
      <?php echo $item['first_name']; ?>
    </p>
  <?php endforeach; ?>﻿
```

**Result**

```
J

D

t

3
```

If I do a `var_dump` this is what I get:

```
string(4) "John"
string(3) "Doe"
string(9) "test test"
string(1) "3"
```

So, I'm not sure if I'm missing something, or if I'm just going about this the wrong way.

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON string has **only one** object, without nested objects or arrays.

So you have to try in this way:

```
$json = json_decode($jsondata, true);
echo $json['first_name'];
```

or in this way:

```
$json = json_decode($jsondata, true);
foreach( $json as $key => $item )
{
    echo $item;
}
```

Comment: Ahhhhh, ok. So, I don't "technically" need the `foreach` loop. I can just call in the data outright with `echo`. Man, I thought I would have to use a `foreach` loop for the data.

Comment: And if you dont convert the OBJECT to and Array you can simple use `$json->first_name` and `$json->last_name` etc

Comment: I have this exact problem but my application will scale to require the foreach... does someone have an actual explanation as to why the above code does not work?

Comment: So the solution I found was that I had to alter my json serialization to put my array of key:value pairs into a larger array. Then everything worked as it was supposed to.