# Looping JSON data only shows the first character

Tags: php, json, foreach, jira

I am trying to output specific information coming from JIRA, I have JSON looping and results showing, but the results furthest down the nest are only showing the first character.

I have tried following the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35539655/php-json-foreach-only-returns-first-character) but this seems to be for results at the top level and I can't seem to get it working with my code.

```
<?php
$username = '*************';
$password = '*************';

$url = '<JIRA-DOMAIN>/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=ICI&fields=key,summary,description&maxResults=10';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

$issue_list = (curl_exec($curl));
$json = json_decode($issue_list, TRUE);
?>

<div class="toto">
    <?php
    foreach($json['issues'] as $obj){   ?>

        <h2><?php echo $obj['id']; ?></h2>

          <?php foreach($obj['fields'] as $parc){ ?>

             <a href="<?php echo $parc['summary']; ?>">
                 <span><?php echo $parc['description']; ?></span>
             </a>

       <?php }
     } ?>
</div>
```

When I echo $issue_list I get the following:

***Output Shortened***

```
{
    "expand":"schema,names",
    "startAt":0,
    "maxResults":10,
    "total":9,
    "issues":[
        {

"expand":"operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
        "id":"10058",
        "self":"<domain>/rest/api/2/issue/10058",
        "key":"ICI-9",
        "fields":{
            "summary":"ToS and PP button removal",
            "description":"The Terms of Service and Privacy Policy buttons go to a page on the website so they can't use the app after. They also go to a page of nothing because they aren't written so they need to be deleted"
        }
    },
    {
        "expand":"operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
        "id":"10048",
        "self":"<domain>/rest/api/2/issue/10048",
        "key":"ICI-1",
        "fields":{
            "summary":"Create Launch Image",
            "description":"Create launch image for app. Resolution should be: 2048px × 1536px\r\n\r\n[~james.whitaker] I got this info from [here|https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/launch-screen/]"
        }
    }
]
}
```

But the loop output only shows the first character for the Description and Summary as seen below but shows the entire ID.

[image: Output Screenshot]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in this `foreach` loop:

```
     <?php foreach($obj['fields'] as $parc){ ?>

         <a href="<?php echo $parc['summary']; ?>">
             <span><?php echo $parc['description']; ?></span>
         </a>

   <?php }
```

`$parc` will have the value of `$obj['fields']['summary']` and then `$obj['fields']['description']` in the loop, so when you try and index it with `['summary']` you are using an invalid index which is translating to 0 (hence the single character). Try this instead (remove the `foreach`):

```
     <a href="<?php echo $obj['fields']['summary']; ?>">
         <span><?php echo $obj['fields']['description']; ?></span>
     </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think `fields` isn't array.

Change `$parc['summary']` to `$obj['fields']['summary']`